# Take pictures of the whole activity sometimes crash the App

Tags: java, android

When I press the "Share" button, my app takes a screenshot of all the activity(even no visible parts) and the share it via intent. I figured out that sometime it works and sometimes it doesn't. I can't understand the problem.
That's my code:

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkPermission();


        }
    });
// Inside the checkPermission method, if the user allow them:
Bitmap bitmapScreen = takeScreenshot();
saveBitmap(bitmapScreen);
} 

 public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

    rechoose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    share.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    rootView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    rootView.layout(0, 0, rootView.getMeasuredWidth(), rootView.getMeasuredHeight());
    rootView.buildDrawingCache(true);

    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String randomUUIDString = "/" + uuid.toString() + ".png";
    rechoose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + randomUUIDString);
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("errorFileNotFound", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("Exception", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(RateActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", imagePath);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

I got this error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at com.my.name.myapp.RateActivity.saveBitmap(RateActivity.java:211)
```

The line 211 is:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

It's a little bit strange, because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.
On my activity I load an image from my gallery. With some image that I pick from gallery, the app takes the screenshot, with others it doesn't.
Obviously, if the app didn't take the screenshot, then I got a nullPointerException on bitmap.compress. But I can't figured out why it doesn't take the screenshot.
If I write the takeScreenshot() method like this, it works anytime:

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {


View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}
```

Comment: Sometime if you don't get proper path then you will not get bitmap that cause an issue. Must be sure you'r getting proper path while saving to storage.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bitmap is null here. Please debug the value of bitmap and cross check if it is null or not. Or you can use the below code to take a screenshot, put this function n general method and pass your view to it.

```
fun takeScreenshot(context: View?, activity: Activity) {
val now = Date()
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now)
try {
    val mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg"
    // create bitmap screen capture
    context?.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(context?.drawingCache)
    context?.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
    val imageFile = File(mPath)
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, mPath)
    activity.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
    val quality = 100
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream)
    outputStream.flush()
    outputStream.close()
    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.saved_to_gallery), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
} catch (e: Throwable) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: Post your code in Java because OP has already implemented with it.

Comment: Use this link for java code reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot